# Power Query Parametrization - Choose between loading a limited number of rows or a complete rowset using a parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I would like my SQL query in PBI to be defined by parameter. The **Parameter1** is a list of two values `Big` and `Small`. If I set up Parameter1 to `Small` then I want only a sample of data to be loaded. I am doing it this way:

```
let
  ReturnQueryVar = (optional x) => 
  if Parameter1 = "Small" 
  then " and Product in (1, 2, 3)" 
  else "",

  Source = Sql.Database(
    "myservername", 
    "mydatabase",
    [
      Query = "
        select *
        from table
        where
        1=1"
        & ReturnQuery()
    ]
  )
in
  Source
```

I get this error:

Expression.Error: The name 'ReturnQuery' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Update.

Facepalm! It was a typo. ReturnQuery should be ReturnQueryVar.

However, I would like to leave the question open for the part:

```
  ReturnQueryVar = (optional x) => 
  if Parameter1 = "Small" 
  then " and Product in (1, 2, 3)" 
  else ""
```

Does PowerQuery have a syntax for IF:

```
TextVar = IF(Parameter1 = 'S', 'This', 'That' )
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Expression.Error: The name 'ReturnQuery' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: Simple enough :)   PowerQuery can do if's https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/power-query-if-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen syntax like that, but if you like you can create a function that does that, basically a "container" for the `IF` statement of `Power Query`.

For example, you can create a `Blank Query` called `IF` with the following contents.

```
(cond as logical, if_true as any, if_false as any ) => 
 if cond then if_true else if_false
```

Using that function, anywhere it would have similar results and an IF statement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am just sharing here a PowerQuery snippet I ended up with. This code allows you to choose with a parameter between two alternate queries - the first for a sample and the other for the full rowset. It allows to download only a small sample of rows from a large table into Power BI Desktop.

```
let
  QueryCode = if Query_Parameter = "Sample" 
  then 
  "select 1" 
  else 
  "select 2",

  Source = Sql.Database(
    "MyServer", 
    "MyDataBase",
    [ Query = QueryCode ]
  )
in
  Source
```

Prior to that in Power Query Editor > Manage Parameters > Add New Parameter named `Query_Parameter` with 2 text values as a list: "Sample" and "Full" and based on this parameter the source of the query changes. Just replace "select 1" with  anything narrowing your rows like "select top 1000..." or add WHERE condition. "select 2" is your query with full row set.